# XML TASK in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I want to create many destination files with xml task.

### Step 1

I create my xml task for 1 file, it's work fine

[image]

### Step 2

I create my variables

[image: image 2]

### Step 3

I use foreach loop container
[image]

### Step 4

I change connectionstring as variable

[image]

### Step 5

When I execute my package the same destination file is used (same information in my destination table)

[image: image 5]

How can I create (or use variable for destination file)? For example, if I have 1000 input files, I need 1000 output destination files. Someone has idea for this? Thank you.

Comment: Please do not post images, see here how to create a good one:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Except for SSIS questions, where images are generally invaluable due to the graphical nature of configuring tasks

Answer (score 0):

I don't work with the XML source in SSIS but I do a fair bit of work with SSIS otherwise.

The problem you have is that an SSIS Data flow is tightly bound to the metadata of the source and destination components. If you have 1000 source files, all of the same format then your pattern is correct and you will land all 1000 file's worth of data into the destination---whether the destination is a single big bag or a 1000 table/file/etc

However, if you have 1000 different schemas, and the 1001th file will be yet-another-format, then SSIS is not the tool to use. Or, at least not a data flow task. A custom Script Task might be able to handle it but we don't have enough details to confirm/deny suitability. And that's consulting work level of effort, likely nothing you'll get from a free website.

Comment: Hi billinkc. All files have the same schema

Comment: someone has idea?